# BigQuery: Read After Write Consistency (Streaming Inserts)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

As the title states, what is the consistency guarantee for BigQuery with respect to streaming inserts? Will I be able to guarantee a consistent read after inserting rows using streaming insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which Streaming API you are using and which DML you expect to run:

- When using the Legacy Streaming API, "[Data is available for real-time analysis using standard SQL queries immediately after BigQuery successfully acknowledges a tabledata.insertAll request](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability)"
- Using the new Storage Write API, the behaviour is configurable: [You can choose between default stream, committed mode, pending mode, and buffered mode, depending on your requirements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#overview_of_the):

  - **Committed mode and default stream**: "Records are available for reading immediately as you write them to the stream". The difference is that the default stream comes without exactly-once guarantees and, consequently, potentially higher throughputs.
  - **Pending mode**: "Records are buffered in a pending state until you commit the stream. Once a stream is committed, all of the data written to the stream is available for reading"
  - **Buffered mode**: "Records are buffered until you flush the stream. Flushing advances a cursor to a specified offset and makes all the records up to that offset visible"
- Nevertheless, "[rows that were written to a table recently by using streaming (the tabledata.insertall method or the Storage Write API) cannot be modified with UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#limitations)" and "[Some recently streamed rows might not be available for table copy typically for a few minutes. In rare cases, this can take up to 90 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability)"
- "[Because BigQuery's streaming API is designed for high insertion rates, modifications to the underlying table metadata are eventually consistent when interacting with the streaming system](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#metadata-errors-for-streaming-inserts)"

So in general terms, when using default streaming, data is promptly available for reading queries after an acknowledged streaming insert.

Comment: How is the consistency with respect to Buffered mode? I understand that Buffered mode in a way lets us perform atomic smaller batch writes, as opposed to pending mode where one can combine several streams as one atomic transaction.

Comment: @muffe The difference is that you cannot control what's being committed on pending mode. It's the full buffer from all streams or nothing (Be careful that "there is no guarantee of how long the data persists" in the temporary buffer before committing it).
On buffered mode, you can control until what offset the buffer will be committed, allowing you to make the data available in steps independent from the ingestion rate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no!!

- Yes, the read is consistent if you get your data just after the streaming insert!
- No if you use partitioning because the streaming data are stored in a buffer and it can take up to 2h to BigQuery to store the data in the correct partition.

So, it depends on how you use your data.